# Power Automate Run History Logging

Tags: power-automate

I have create a power automate flow which reads mail and write the extracted information from mail to excel sheet hosted in share-point. Everytime power automate runs it capture all information at server level and same can be downloaded in .csv file.

Can anyone help me how I can stop power automate to capture the information read from mails in run history logs?

Is there any configuration which can help me to configure what information power automate should persist in log?

Comment: What do you mean by a CSV? That’s not standard functionality so how does it get to a CSV?

Comment: Once you go to full run history of a power automate flow there is an option to download complete run history log in excel file. It basically saves log at server but we have option to download it in .csv format.Check once at your end.

Comment: Ahhhh, ok, cool.  Did you want to do that for security reasons?  Because, there is a way but it can't be isolated to the CSV output, it will also remove the data from the run itself.  That means if you view it wanting to see what the email contained, you won't be able to.  Not sure if that suits you or not.

Comment: @Skin Yes I wanted to do that for data security. Yes removing data from run itself will work for me as I have designed separate flow for logging. Kindly let me know the steps to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your flow step that reads the email, go to Settings and enable Secure Outputs. This will then hide/obscure the data in the flow run. You may also need to do this for subsequent variables/outputs steps depending on your flow.
Have a look at: https://sharepains.com/2020/01/30/secure-input-output-flows-power-automate/